# REST API endpoint for adding information

Tags: rest

I want to put two parameters say name(this will be unique) and location.
I need to take these two from a REST url.
Which approach is better suited

```
1. POST /info/{name} and location as request body(String).
2. POST /info?name=""&location=""
3. POST /info and requestbody containing both as JSON
{
"name": "somename",
"location":"somelocation"
}
```

Comment: It depends on the semantics of your info endpoint. If your name is used as identifier then #1 will go. The most widely used approach is #3 I guess.

Comment: 2 is a GET, also you say you want to put, but you mention only posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#3 is the way to go for two reasons:

1. `/info` is the base URL for a "set of objects" related or of a given type, and as per REST philosophy, you use POST over it to add new elements.
2. When you add an element, you may specify in the contract that a piece of data is the ID of the new element, so that the URL is composed for it as `/info/{ID}`.

This is your #3 case. #1 does not follow that REST philosophy, because you'd convert the element in a container itself. #2 could also be used if you specify in the contract that the data, instead of comming in the body it is in the URL, but #3 is more common.

Comment: I think you are right, but I was waiting for clarification on what he meant by *put*